# Is this approach of running a local virtual machine to act strictly as the remote shell/python interpreter a sensible idea?

Tags: pycharm, ide, virtual-machine

This is less coding and more about my IDE setup. I have this extremely dodgy idea, Spin up a Linux virtual machine running on my windows machine, run Pycharm on windows and set up a remote SSH interpreter on said Linux virtual machine. So I'll effectively be running my python environment on my remote machine. Is this a sensible idea? Is there a better-supported way?

Comment: I'll just note, I run Pycharm right in a Parrot VM, and it works fine. You need a fair amount of memory, but PHPStorm and Pycharm run almost as well in the VM as they do on the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Windows subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-index) is an officially supported full Linux virtual machine that runs concurrently with Windows. If you wanted to get fancy with networking or just want your Linux dev environment totally isolated from your computer your could run ubuntu on [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) in your WSL2, which has the added benefit of being a completely even environment every time you want it

Comment: Ah I kinda like the docker approach actually. I just tested it out and it works quite nicely.Can you also change the default terminal to be a bash shell from a docker container?

Comment: Sure, my ubuntu container is using bash right now, you might be running alpine Linux (if you ran alpine:latest or `FROM alpine:latest`) which uses sh by default, but can add bash with `apk add bash` and then running it with `bash`, or you could use ubuntu:bionic (or ubuntu:focal etc) which uses bash by default

Comment: As a note of warning though docker has a habit of eating all your ram in WSL2, but you can configure WSL2 to [never use more ram than it should](https://medium.com/@lewwybogus/how-to-stop-wsl2-from-hogging-all-your-ram-with-docker-d7846b9c5b37)

Comment: Does that mean I'll have to `docker exec -t -i {container} bash` into it every time or can I set it up so that my IDE's terminal tab auto spins up the shell?